# AngularJS: What's the correct syntax to share a factory service among custom directives with controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I've 2 custom directives and a controller that all need to share some data. The following doesn't compile. What's the correct syntax to do this?

**flight-service.js (shared):**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('flight-service', []);

  app.factory('flightService', function() {
    return {
      srcAirport: '',
      destAirport: '',
      departureDt: '',
      arrivalDt: ''
    }
  })
})();
```

**travel-dt.js:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('travel-dt', ['ui.bootstrap', 'flight-service']);

  app.directive('travelDt', ['flightService', function(flightService) {
    var travelDtCtrl = ['$scope',
      function($scope, flightService) {
        $scope.flight = flightService;

 ... more stuff
```

**airport-search.js:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('airport-search', ['ui.bootstrap', 'flight-service']);

  app.directive('airportSearch', ['flightService', function(flightService) {
    var airportSearchCtrl = ['$http', '$scope', '$log',
      function($http, $scope, $log) {
        $scope.flight = flightService;

... more stuff
```

**app.js:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('travelApp', ['airport-search', 'travel-dt', 'flight-service']);

  app.controller('FlightSearchCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'flightService',
    function($scope, $http, $filter, flightService) {
      $scope.flight = flightService;

... more stuff
```

**index.html:**

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/airport-search.js"></script>
<script src="js/travel-dt.js"></script>
<script src="js/flight-service.js"></script>
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
travel-dt.js:45 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module travelApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module airport-search due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'airport-search' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=airport-search
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:68:12
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:1986:17
```

**Edit 1:**

After reordering the JS imports in `index.html` as suggested, and refactoring `airport-search.js` as below, I'm now getting an error as follows. I think the `scope: {...}` is suspect though I don't know how to correct it.

```
TypeError: definition.match is not a function
    at angular.js:6982
    at forEach (angular.js:350)
    at parseIsolateBindings (angular.js:6981)
    at parseDirectiveBindings (angular.js:7015)
```

**airport-search.js:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('airport-search', ['ui.bootstrap', 'flight-service']);

  app.directive('airportSearch', function() {
    var airportSearchCtrl = ['$http', '$scope', '$log', 'flightService',
      function($http, $scope, $log, flightService) {
        $scope.flight = flightService;

        $scope.findAirports = function(val) {
          return $http.get('airports', {
            params: {
              searchTerm: val
            }
          }).then(function(searchResults) {
            return searchResults.data.map(function(airport) {
              return airport;
            });
          }).catch(function(searchResults) {
            $log.error(searchResults);
          });
        };
      }];

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'pages/airport-search.html',
      scope: {
        flight: {
          srcAirport: '=',
          destAirport: '='
        }
      },
      controller: airportSearchCtrl
    };
  });
})();
```

**Edit 2:**

**airport-search.html:**

```
<div class="row search-label">
    <div ng-show="loadingAirports" class="col-md-6">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Searching...
    </div>
    <div ng-show="noResults" class="col-md-6">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row search-panel">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="model in [srcAirport, destAirport] track by $index">
        <pre>Model: {{model | json}}</pre>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search-box" ng-model="model"
                   uib-typeahead="airport as airport.name for airport in findAirports($viewValue)"
                   typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-loading="loadingAirports" typeahead-no-results="noResults">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 3:**

[Live Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SmedflEE7J0DmB4fMAGR)

Type 'sea' (w/o quotes) in the first 2 text boxes, choose from the pop up, choose a departure date, and click search button. See the error because the shared service is not available.

Comment: change the order of the files in the index.html. Start with flight-service and then travel and airport and last app.js

Comment: Also it looks a bit weird in your travel-dt.js. It looks like you're injecting both scope and flightservice in the controller-variable, but you only have scope as minification safed.

Comment: @Gustav I'm not a JS guy. Please show me using the code snippets what you think is wrong.

Comment: How are you using this airport search directive in the html?

Comment: You should remove the scope property of the directive object, or set it to `socpe: {}`. Since you are setting the flight property of scope inside the controller i doubt you're using the html to inject the flight...

Comment: @Gustav added `airport-search.html` in edit 2

Comment: I didn't mean the template. I meant the html where you use the directive. But try first fix the injection faults and change the scope thing

Comment: Did it work with fixing the injection on app.js and removing scope from directive?

Comment: @Gustav No, see edit 3.

Comment: I'm not getting any error you're talking about. But i noticed you have some faults regarding ng-model and scope, how you expect the values to be set. I did some edits on your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HsvXBJrQrWsFjPCRb9GO?p=preview)

Comment: @Gustav The error I was talking about was visible in the Chrome console. Anyway, I see what you did, that you qualified the model with `flight` in the html. I'd thought about that but didn't particularly like it as it made the view aware of the model name. But it does do what I'm after and I'm not as picky about front end design as I'm about back end. I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors, that actually are sort of explained in the errors themselves.

First: `travel-dt.js:45 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`
It's hard to tell exact row numbers, but looking at the provided code, your controller variable declared inside the directive function is missing one minification safe of flightservice. It should look like this

```
var travelDtCtrl = ['$scope', 'flightService',
      function($scope, flightService) {
        $scope.flight = flightService;
```

Now i'm not sure if this is the actual syntax error. But this looks like it's wrong nonetheless. You should look at row 45, and see what sort of `Unexpected token` might be there. Ie some misplaced character.

Second: `angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module travelApp`

So this is because youre trying to instatiate travelApp with other modules injected that doesn't exist yet. Put the js-files in the order you need them:

```
<script src="js/flight-service.js"></script>
<script src="js/airport-search.js"></script>
<script src="js/travel-dt.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean like this?

(function() {
  var app = angular.module('airport-search', ['ui.bootstrap', 'flight-service']);

app.directive('airportSearch', ['flightService', function(flightService) {
  var airportSearchCtrl = ['$http', '$scope', '$log', 'flightService',
      function($http, $scope, $log, flightService) {
        $scope.flight = flightService;

Comment: yes, you are doing it right in the airportSearch. But as I said, take a look at row 45. Is this row 45 or is it something else there? The error states there is a syntax error on row 45

Comment: I noticed you have the same wrongly injection in app.js, regarding $filter

Comment: Doesn't work. Unfortunately, I found some of your suggestions unclear, perhaps due to my lack of Angular knowledge, and thus it's possible that we're not on the same page. See my edit 3, I've added a live Plunker example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<script src="js/airport-search.js"></script>
<script src="js/travel-dt.js"></script>
<script src="js/flight-service.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```